# Pass variables from .bat file to vbscript in relation to iMacros iimset

Tags: vbscript, imacros

I'm trying to minimize the number of vbs files that I have for a number of imacro testing I have. I'm fairly new to scripting and I'm still learning to make my code simpler.

Summary:

1. I have one imacros (iim file) of which the URL parameter is being supplied by a vbs file. I have 47 parameters ie. http://www.domain.com/page.jsp?{{url}}

   The value of {{url}} is supplied by different vbs file with the same code but different parameters using iimset, ie.

   `var=iim1.iimset("url","link1"}}`

   This part is the only difference in all of my 47 vbs file.
   Ref - http://wiki.imacros.net/iimSet%28%29
2. all of these vbscript is being called by batch file with interval of 15 minutes each.

My question is:

1. Can I pass the variable from batch file to vbscript?
2. Or is there another easy way to do this?

I've been looking for answers for two days already. I hope you guys can lend a hand. Thank you so much again.

Comment: Are your VBS files being run using Windows Scripting Host (i.e. cscript.exe or wscript.exe) or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about imacros, but vbs scripts (via Windows Script Host) support parameters, which can be accessed by the `Arguments` property of the `WScript` object. You can have named or anonymous parameters. Eg a batch file that runs a VBScript file

```
REM run test.vbs with a named parameter and an anonymous parameter
cscript test.vbs /a:"a value" "another value"

PAUSE
```

and the VBScript itself:

option explicit

```
dim param1: param1 = WScript.Arguments.Named("a")
dim param2: param2 = WScript.Arguments.UnNamed(0)

WScript.Echo "param1: " & param1 & " param2: " & param2
```

will output

> param1: a value param2: another value

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b05k8s(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thank you for the code. I tried it and it worked. I just need another big favor from you. Can you give me a sample code of how can I insert the value in here? 
Following the syntax from here http://wiki.imacros.net/iimSet%28%29
int ret_code = iimSet ( String VARNAME, String VARVALUE )

this is my code - 
var= iim1.iimset("offernumber", "this is where the value from bat file should be placed")

the string VARVALUE must be a plain text.

The example here is a good lead but since I need to learn more about scripting it would be easier for me to follow your ways because it's time constraint.